# Ordering of WP_Query results

Tags: wordpress

I have a shortcode, that takes a list of post ids, as an argument.

```
[my_sc team_title="Team" posts_per_page="-1" ids="130,11687,11688,11689, 13767,11691,11693,11694,11695,11696,11697"]
```

I need to output the posts on the page, using the order of the ids, as entered into the shortcode above.

I tried removing the order and orderby from the code below, hoping without explicit ordering provided, it would output the posts using the ordering of of the ids in $ids.

```
$team_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'crb_team',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'ID',
    'post__in' => $ids,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
));
```

The WP_Query results are output like so:

```
while ( $team_query->have_posts() ): $team_query->the_post();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you exclude the `order` and `orderby` arguments, your query will use the default values (DESC and date).

You're setting the posts in the query with the `post__in` argument and WordPress supports that as an `orderby` value.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

```
$team_query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'crb_team',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'post__in',
    . . .
```